# How to flatten a curved object

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have a complex mesh of a piece of clothing that I want to flatten out so that it looks like it has been taken off.

How can I do this while keeping the detail of the mesh? I have tried with a *Curve Deform* modifier but it won't flatten a curve, only curve a flat shape.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image showing your object.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to unwrap or flatten a crumpled or wrinkled mesh object. Maybe look into [Laplacian Smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/laplacian_smooth.html) or Smooth modifiers, but I do't think that will be enough.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to make cloth which is flattened because it lays on the surface then Cloth modifier is best solution.